# Convert this JSON data to list of objects in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

My input is JSON data. It looks like:

```
[
    {
        "shortName": "av",
        "longName": "average",
        "Color": "black",
        "fromValue": "45",
        "toValue": "59"
    },
    {
        "shortName": "g",
        "longName": "good",
        "Color": "red",
        "fromValue": "35",
        "toValue": "68"
    }
]
```

I need to convert this data to a list of objects (`PerfLevel` class). How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) or [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to read the JSON as `List` or array of expected type.
With Jackson:

`` ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // reuse if multiple calls
MyPOJO[] pojos = mapper.readValue(jsonSource, MyPojo[].class); // with `List`, need to use `TypeReference`
// or, if you do not have matching MyPOJO type:
List<Object> pojosAsMaps = mapper.readValue(jsonSource, List.class); ``

There are many other ways you could do it, like reading as JSON tree (`JsonNode`).
It all depends on whether you can easily model structure as Java class (if so, most convenient) or not.

Comment: tahnk you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Just use the org.json.* package.

You can look it up under http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/package-summary.html JSONArray and JSONObject will be the most interesting code snippets.

Also your JSON-Object is not really well formated, you should make an Array of your Objects first, like:

```
users : [{
    "shortname" : "g",
    "moreAttributes" : ""
}, {
    "shortname" : "h",
    "moreAttributes" : ""
}]
```

Using this array-structure you can add objects information outside the array. For example an errormessage.

now you can access your json-file with some simple methods:

```
JSONObject jObj = //the json file you loaded
JSONArray jArr = jObj.getArray("users");
JSONObject jUser;


//at this point you can iterate over your array and get information via:
jUser = jArr.getJSONObject(1)

//now you can get all the information from the jUser object
//e.g.
jUser.getString("shortname");
```